# The case of the sexist plant

Tags: science-based, evolution, environment, creature-design

Let's say we have a species of plant, that, for whatever reason, only wants to be pollenated by female pollinators. Maybe this gives some advantage to the plant and/or pollinator.

Why would a plant only want to be pollenated by a specific *sex*? How would it tell the difference?

Bonus question: How would the plant defend against *non-female* would-be pollinators?

Feel free to make up evolutionary traits, but if you can tie it to real-world examples that would be even better!

Comment: For example, only female bees pollinate plants. [Male bees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drone_(bee)) do not pollinate plants. (And "male" and "female" are sexes, not genders. Gender is the social construct, which may or may not correspond to the biological sex. A female bee could very well want to be called Mister and wear shirts, and a male bee might want to be called Ms. and wear blouses.)

Comment: Good point, I fixed it!

Answer (score 3):

Ultimately, the answer you seek lies in [Enzymes](https://www.livescience.com/45145-how-do-enzymes-work.html). These are essentially biological catalysts that greatly increase the rate of specific biochemical reactions in the body.

Tie this to a hormone, like [Estrogen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estrogen) (which is found in greater levels in females) and you have a biological catalyst that may only occur in female pollinators.

The mechanism would be that the male pollen would be either toxic or infertile to the female plant in its raw state; it needs to be activated via an enzymatic process that relies on estrogen, progesterone or some other hormone that is found in greater quantities in a female. So, male pollinators can disperse the pollen, but not activate it.

I couldn't find any examples of this working in real life; Bees for instance have a distinct difference in how they operate between the genders and while male bees seek nectar directly from flowers, they lack the pollen sacs on their legs that the females have to collect (and disperse) the pollen. So, they operate in completely different ways and therefore are not helpful as an analogue of this process.

The other important thing to note is that evolutionarily speaking, the plant is creating a rod for its own back and is highly unlikely to form this kind of symbiosis with a specific gender of pollinator for the simple reason that if for any reason that gender doesn't drop by, the pollination cannot be successful. Ultimately, a plant is better off having the pollen in a ready-to-use form, so that *anything*, including wind, can fertilise nearby flowers. This kind of evolution creates an environmental niche that can easily go wrong with a simple change of environment so I would not expect such a plant to evolve naturally, or if it did, not to last across eons of evolution.

But, the idea that a female hormone acts as an enzyme on pollen to activate it is not all that far-fetched from a biological engineering perspective at the very least.

Answer (score 3):

**Females might get around more.**

In general, females of any species invest more energy in offspring than males.  Eggs require more resource investment than sperm.  This is true for pollinators too.

If a female needs more energy, it must go get it.  Assuming pollinators are visiting flowers for food, a female might visit more flowers than a male: it needs more food.

Pollen is a resource as well.  It makes sense to bestow it on the pollinators who will spread it most widely.  If the females are visiting more flowers they will spread the pollen more widely.  In that case it makes sense to give all your pollen to females.

---

As regards how to make that happen it is much tricker.  "Pollinators" can include a wide range of animals with very size and body habitus.  Some flowers exclude certain pollinators with flower shape; for example those that want only hummingbirds have long deep nectaries that only a hummingbird can reach. Some flowers have a flap that only robust pollinators like bees can lift.   If you are offering nectar and you have a specific pollinator type with sexual dimorphism then you can use that dimorphism to allow the females and bar the males.

The other way I can think of is to select for females by mimicking the attraction they use to find an egg laying site.  For example still water with algae will attract female mosquitoes to lay eggs but not males.  If your attraction is a cheat (smells like good laying food plant substrate but actually is not) this is not a long term evolutionary strategy - the females you fool will waste their eggs and you will select for those you cannot fool.  But if you actually provide a good egg laying environment (and a flower could definitely harbor water and algae for mosquito larvae) then it is a good long term strategy.  This would only work for females that distribute eggs at more than one site.